# Creating Directory in Android API 22(Lollipop) and 23(Marshmallow)

Tags: android

I am developing an android application that require files(images) to be saved on the devices in order to access them later. I need to create a directory(folder) and then put this stuffs(images) in it
I have this code running on API 19(Kitkat) but does not work on lollipop and the latest marshmallow.

Codes

```
 String stored = null;

    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() ;


    File folder = new File(sdcard.getAbsoluteFile() , "PropertyImages");

    Log.i("Folder Name",folder.toString());
    if (folder.exists()){
        Log.w("Folder Exist","Folder Exists");
    }else{
        Log.w("Folder NOT Exist","Folder NOT Exist");
    }

    if (folder.mkdir()){
        Log.w("Folder Created","Folder Created");
    }else{
        Log.w("Folder is NOT Created","Folder is NOT  Created");
    }

    File file = new File(folder.getAbsoluteFile(), filename + ".jpg") ;
    if (file.exists())
        return stored ;

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        stored = "success";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stored;
}
```

In Kitkat it Worked. In Lollipop and Above it Gives File Not Created

Manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: You forgot to tell -in words- which directory you use.

Comment: Put your files in the one of getExternalFilesDir(s) instead.

Comment: @greenapps , Please can you show me a code reference. I do not seem to understand. Thanks my man

Comment: Define "does not work" - what *does* it do? Is there an error message, or a stacktrace?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek The log displays the "Folder is NOT  Created" message. Which means the folder was not created. But this only happens in lollipop and above

Comment: Looks like you're trying to create the directory even if it already exists.
Technically, this should fail if the directory already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got it solved. Thanks to @greenapps and @GreyBeardedGeek.
@greenapp helped me a lot and got me to do a research and reading on getExternalFilesDir()
This is my Solution in case Someone needs it in the future

```
public static String createExternalStoragePrivateFile(Bitmap bitmap,String imagename,Context ctx) {
    File file = new File(ctx.getExternalFilesDir("PW"), imagename + "jpg");
String stored= "Stored";
    try

    {
        // Very simple code to copy a picture from the application's
        // resource into the external file.  Note that this code does
        // no error checking, and assumes the picture is small (does not
        // try to copy it in chunks).  Note that if external storage is
        // not currently mounted this will silently fail.
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

    catch(
            IOException e
            )

    {
        // Unable to create file, likely because external storage is
        // not currently mounted.
        Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing ");
    }

    return stored;
}
```